# On AWS EC2: membase SERVER_ERROR proxy write to downstream

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, couchbase, membase

I have setup membase server on AWS EC2 instance.
I security groups I have opened all ports for client's IP address. When I access it through telnet (using port 11211) I get following error

```
membase SERVER_ERROR proxy write to downstream
```

But when I change settings in security group to allow access to everyone(0.0.0.0/0) rather than specific IP, it works fine.

In first case client have access to membase server, thats why it connects using telnet, but gives error for queries.

I can not leave all ports open for everyone. Please help to solve this.

Comment: I solved this by my own. Actually in my membase cluster setup, due to my security settings one node on cluster was not able to communicate with other. I have opened ports for other nodes then it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by my own. Actually in my membase cluster setup, due to my security settings one node on cluster was not able to communicate with other. I have opened ports for other nodes then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem on a one-node Couchbase.

I've run `kill -TERM` against the PID of the process serving the affected bucket. Couchbase restarted the killed process and things started working normally.

I guess full restart would fix it too.